# How to join two lines and remove unnecessary spaces in Vim

Tags: vim

In [Source Insight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Insight), when two lines are joined, the extra spaces will be shrunk. For example:

```
This is line one,<space><space>
<space><space>and this is line two
```

will be joined to:

```
This is line one,<space>and this is line two
```

But in Vim, the join command will produce:

```
This is line one,<space><space>and this is line two
```

How do I get the same result as Source Insight does?

Comment: slightly nitpicking note: if you didn't use two spaces in both examples you could see where those spaces come from...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't configure  that with options, unfortunately. It  is hard coded
that lines with trailing spaces will be detected this way. And generally
trailing space  is not desired. You  can consider the Vim's  idea to be:
*"if there  is trailing whitespace,  it might be important  to preserve.
Otherwise  it  wouldn't  be  there"*.  So  the  next  line  has  leading
whitespace removed and joined:

`````
hello```
`there

" When joined:
hello```there

hello```
``there

" joined:
hello```there

hello````
`there

" joined
hello````there
`````

You could  change this behaviour with  a map. This would  overwrite your
`J` key to first remove trailing whitespace and then join the lines:

```
nnoremap J :s/\s*$//<cr>J
vnoremap J :s/\s*$//<cr>gvJ
```

Comment: Or just `:s/\v\s*\n\s*/ /`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura True, but this does eliminate the other `J` features such as considering the `'joinspaces'` options, `j` flag in `'cpo'` and the other flags in `'fo'`. Also, this `\v` is not needed if we're going to aim a short solution :)

Comment: Heh. `\v` is there because my first version used `\s+` instead of `\s*`. :)

Comment: Will this solution impact multiline operation?